# Uncaught TypeError while trying to fill an image source depending on a condition

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I am trying to change a link to http/https depending on the condition. The code which is working is below

```
<script>
  var _comscore = _comscore || [];
  _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "7109919" });
  (function () {
    var s = document.createElement("script"), el = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.async = true;
    s.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el);
  })();
</script>
<noscript>
  <img src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=2&c2=7109919&cv=2.0&cj=1" />
</noscript>
```

What I try to do is to change the 'noscript' part. In 'noscript' section, the code needs to be changed depending on the http/https protocol;

If the protocol is http, the link needs to start with 'b.scorecardresearch.com'
if the protocol is https, the link needs to start with 'sb.scorecardresearch.com'

This is my code and I am trying to fill the source of the img like this

```
{# Comscore Tag #}
<noscript>
  <img id="iScorecardresearch" src="" />
</noscript>

<script>
  var _comscore = _comscore || [];
  _comscore.push({ c1: "2", c2: "7109919" });
  (function () {
    var s = document.createElement("script"), el = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; s.async = true;
    document.getElementById("iScorecardresearch").src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/p?c1=2&c2=7109919&cv=2.0&cj=1";
    s.src = (document.location.protocol == "https:" ? "https://sb" : "http://b") + ".scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js";
    el.parentNode.insertBefore(s, el);
    var ns = document.createElement("noscript"), elns = document.getElementsByTagName("noscript")[0];
  })();
</script>
```

But I get an error which is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null'

Since I am new in frontend and JavaScript, I am stuck in this error, anyone can suggest any solution to solve this error? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`iScorecardresearch` is hidden inside of a `noscript`. The browser won't be able to access it.